# Accessing a variable inside the method of a class

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter, local

I'm creating a budgeting program using Tkinter/Python. This is the basics of my code:

```
class Expense:
  def __init__(self):
    def Save(self)
       TotalAmount = blah
```

So I need to access `TotalAmount` outside of the class but I'm not sure how I would go about this.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply create a variable inside the `__init__()` method which gets called as soon as a class is initialized, and then you can change the value of the variable which would get reflected outside the class as well.

It seems that you were trying to create a method `save()` for the class so I did the same for you, If you don't want your `save()` method to take any arguments then you can also use `def save(self):`

```
class Expense:
    def __init__(self):
        #Do some initializations here
        self.TotalAmount = 0
    def save(self, amount):
        self.TotalAmount = amount


exp = Expense()
print exp.TotalAmount
>>> 0
exp.save(10)
print exp.TotalAmount
>>> 10
```

Comment: [Link to my code](http://pastebin.com/vgypwVwn)

That's my code there, I know it's extremely inefficient and messy but I'm just trying to get this one part working. Could you or someone else have a look?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either add the variable as a property on the object (`self.TotalAmount = blah`) or make it a [global](https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/global-statement.html) variable:

```
class Expense:
  def __init__(self):
    def Save(self)
       global TotalAmount
       TotalAmount = blah
```

The first solution is the preferred one because having a lot of global variables will make your code hard to read. You should strive for [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)) because it makes it easier to maintain the code in the future (changing one part of the code is less likely to break other parts).

Comment: Link to my code That's my code there, I know it's extremely inefficient and messy but I'm just trying to get this one part working. Could you or someone else have a look?