# Accessing a variable from inside the class

Tags: python, function, class, variables, tkinter

I'm creating a budgeting program using Tkinter/Python but I've come to a standstill. This is the basics of my code:

```
class Expense:
  def __init__(self):
    self.testEntry = Entry
  def Save(self)
     self.flag = 2 #example
     TotalAmount = testEntry.get()*flag
```

I need to access `TotalAmount` outside of the class but I'm not sure how I would go about this.

Comment: You **can't** access `TotalAmount` outside of the class - if you need to, either `return` it or make it an *instance attribute* like `testEntry` (which, FYI, is the `Entry` class not an `Entry` instance...)

Comment: In fact, I see you've [already been told this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30479191/3001761). Why should anyone waste their time telling you again?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `return` statement:

```
class Expense:
  def __init__(self):
  self.testEntry = Entry

   def Save(self)
       self.flag = 2 #example
       TotalAmount = testEntry.get()*flag
       return TotalAmount
```

And then call the class and the function.

```
e = Expense()
print e.Save()
```